# Set custom html attribute to child element of material ui component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have to add the custom HTML5 attribute "data-metrics" to the span element, but I'm not sure how to achieve that using the ListItemText Material UI component.
Component API Documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item-text/

This is my code at the moment:

```
<li>
  <ListItem button key={`list_item_${index}`}
    component={Link} to={data.url}
    activeClassName={classes.activeLink} partiallyActive={true}
    focusVisibleClassName={classes.buttonOnFocus}>
     <ListItemText primary={data.name} 
       data-metrics={`{"btnname":"${data.name.toLowerCase()}"}`}/>
  </ListItem>
</li>
```

And this is what it is generating:
[Attribute is being set to div element instead of span(child)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFVRd.png)

Note the data-metrics attribute is being set to the div element instead of the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the "primaryTypographyProps" prop inside the  component. At least I think that's what the docs are saying.

I think you need to pass it an object like so:

`<ListItemText primaryTypographyProps={{"data-metrics": "test"}} />`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for showing me what I've missed in the docs hahaha

Comment: My pleasure, and for what it's worth, it wasn't the most intuitive prop name out there, so it'd be easy to miss. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use useRef hook for this purpose, after you found an element in your ref.current object you can invoke `ref.current.setAttribute("data-metrics", VALUE)`
[It forwards ref to a root element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWwi4.png)